# Python download image with lxml

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, lxml

I need to find an image in a HTML code similar to this one:

```
...
<a href="/example/1"> 
    <img id="img" src="http://example.net/example.jpg" alt="Example" />
</a>
...
```

I am using lxml and requests.

Here is the code:

```
import lxml
from lxml import html
import requests

url = 'http://www.example.com'

r = requests.get(url)
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(r.content)

img = tree.get_element_by_id("img")
f = open("image.jpg",'wb')
f.write(requests.get(img['src']).content)
```

But i am getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Name/Documents/Python/Example/Script.py", line 13, in <module>
    s = requests.get(img['src'])
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/lxml/lxml.etree.pyx", line 1052, in lxml.etree._Element.__getitem__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:38272)
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an index
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Suggestion: read the docs and please fix the html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try `f.write(requests.get(img.attrib['src']).content)`

Answer (score 1):

```
import lxml.html
import requests

url = 'http://www.example.com/'
tree = lxml.html.parse(url)
img = tree.get_element_by_id('img')
img_url = img.attrib['src']

with open('image.jpg', 'wb') as outf:
    data = requests.get(img_url).content
    outf.write(data)
```

Comment: img = tree.get_element_by_id('img')
it doesn't work this time, it says:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Example/Documents/Python/Example/Script.py", line 6, in <module>
    img = tree.get_element_by_id('img')
AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._ElementTree' object has no attribute 'get_element_by_id'

i tried to substitute tree = lxml.html.parse(url) with 
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(requests.get(url).content)

and now it works, thank for help!