# How to download image using lxml from CNN Business

Tags: python, html, xpath, beautifulsoup, lxml

I have gone through very similar stackoverflow page: [Python download image with lxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11566596/python-download-image-with-lxml)
but still that did not work for my case.

I would like to get some help downloading images from CNN business forecast page.
Here is my code so far:

## MWE

```py
import lxml.html
import requests


ticker = "AAL"
ticker = ticker.upper()
url = f"https://money.cnn.com/quote/forecast/forecast.html?symb={ticker}"

xpath = '//*[@id="wsod_forecasts"]/div[1]/div/img'

response = requests.get(url)
parsed_page = lxml.html.fromstring(response.content) # this gives a list


# from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11566596/python-download-image-with-lxml
# this also fails
tree = lxml.html.parse(url)
img = tree.get_element_by_id('img')
img_url = img.attrib['src']

with open('image.jpg', 'wb') as outf:
    data = requests.get(img_url).content
    outf.write(data)
```

## Question

How to download the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your `parsed_page` add:

```
img_url = "http:"+parsed_page.xpath('//*[@id="wsod_forecasts"]/div[1]/div/img')[0].attrib['src']
```

or alternatively:

```
img_url = "http:"+parsed_page.xpath('//*[@id="wsod_forecasts"]//img')[0].attrib['src']
```

and then run your `with open()` and it should download.